# try catch inside throws IOException

Tags: java, android

I have a function like this

```
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request request = chain.request();
                Response response = chain.proceed(request);
                try{
                   Utilities.showRequestLog(request,response,TAG);
                }catch(IOException e){
                   Log.e(TAG,e.getMessage());
                   return response;
                }
                return response;
            }
```

When I run `intercept` method if function `Utilities.showRequestLog(request,response,TAG);` has `Exception`. It's never go to **catch** block and always throws `Exception` outside.My question is how can I make my code go to **catch** if `Utilities.showRequestLog(request,response,TAG);` has exception?

**EDIT :**

here is my `Utilities.showRequestLog(request,response,TAG);`.Because I just want to show request and response log (for debug case). So if `showRequestLog` function get exception, the `intercept` function still return response to show data. I dont what throw exception outside when showRequestLog have exception because it really another sense

```
public static void showRequestLog(final Request request,final Response response,final String apiName) throws IOException{
            if(Constants.Config.SHOW_REQUEST_LOG) {

                        Log.e(apiName, "--Start--");
                        Log.e(apiName, " request method = " + request.method());
                        Log.e(apiName, " request Url = " + request.urlString());
                        Log.e(apiName, " request header  " + request.headers().toString());
                        if (request.method().equals("POST")) {
                            if (request.body() != null) {
                                Buffer buffer = new Buffer();
                                request.body().writeTo(buffer);
                                Log.e(apiName, " request Params = " + buffer.readUtf8());
                            } else {
                                Log.e(apiName, " request Params = empty post params");
                            }
                        }
                        Log.e(apiName, "response data = " + response.body().string());
                        Log.e(apiName, "response code = " + response.code());
                        Log.e(apiName, "response msg = " + response.message());
                        Log.e(apiName, "--End--");
            }
    }
```

Comment: Um, that's what you're doing right now, isn't it?  Catching when showRequestLog is throwing an exception?

Comment: dont throws the exception

Comment: please post you `StackTrace` i think you r missing something...

Comment: I don't believe you. You aren't giving us all of the facts. Either `showRequestLog()` is throwing a different exception type or `Log.e()` is throwing the exception. Some simple debug (like printing the stacktrace) will tell you what is happening.

Comment: if the control is not entering the catch block that means, showRequestLog() is not throwing an IOException but some other exception, you need to check your logs find out what exception it is, then decide how to handle it.

Comment: @John3136 because it dont go to Catch show I can print stacktrace. Because I just want to return response if showRequesLog has exception, so I dont need to know why showRequestLog has error

Comment: @MrJ - from your question: `and always throws Exception outside` - catch and print where it is happening. Or change the catch to catch all exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

`Utilities.showRequestLog` should throw an `IOException` only if it throws any other runtime exception it will not get caught. You can add another catch block
`catch(RuntimeException e)`, Ideally we should not catch runtime exceptions, if we don't know what to do with them.

Comment: I dont want to know why showRequestLog has exception . I just want to return response if showRequestLog has exception

Comment: In that case change catch(IOException e) to catch(Exception e)

Answer (score 0):

Test this code.

```
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();
            Response response = chain.proceed(request);
            try{
               Utilities.showRequestLog(request,response,TAG);
            }catch(IOException e){
               Log.e(TAG,e.getMessage());
               throw new IOException(e.getMessage())
            }
            return response;
        }
```

or

```
       public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();
            Response response = chain.proceed(request);
            return response;
        }
```

Comment: You don't  thug `IOException` in try .

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
try{
    Utilities.showRequestLog(request,response,TAG);
} catch(IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG,e.getMessage());
    return response;
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // do something for Exception other than IOException
}
```